# Force 5 minute interval to datetime SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to force the date time to make it 5 minute interval given the date and minutes my input is below

```
2020-02-04 07:55:04.000
2020-02-04 07:49:04.000
2020-02-04 07:41:04.000
2020-02-04 07:38:04.000
2020-02-04 07:35:04.000
2020-02-04 07:32:04.000
2020-02-04 07:25:04.000
2020-02-04 07:20:04.000
------------NULL------  07:15:04.000
------------NULL------  07:10:04.000
------------NULL------  07:05:04.000
2020-02-04 07:05:04.000
```

What I want as output is:

```
2020-02-04 07:55:04.000
2020-02-04 07:50:04.000
2020-02-04 07:45:04.000
2020-02-04 07:40:04.000
2020-02-04 07:35:04.000
2020-02-04 07:30:04.000
2020-02-04 07:25:04.000
2020-02-04 07:20:04.000
------------NULL------  07:15:04.000
------------NULL------  07:10:04.000
------------NULL------  07:05:04.000
2020-02-04 07:05:04.000
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: im sorry im using sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive cte.  Date/time functions are notoriously database dependent, so it would be something like:

```
with cte as (
      select col, lead(col) over (order by col) as next_col
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 5, col), next_col
      from cte
      where dateadd(minute, 5, col) < next_col
     )
select col
from cte
order by col;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c886966205b477607b655b1514ca7bf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: im having issue with the code seems the next_col cant be read by the sql server

Comment: @DrianDrian . . . I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: seems its not forcing the time to be interval of 5 minutes

Comment: 2020-02-04 07:38:04.000
2020-02-04 07:35:04.000
2020-02-04 07:32:04.000
This time should be force to be interval of 5minutes can you help me check while its not showing

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of this trick, but I haven't tried it myself yet:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeMap
(
    StartTime Time NOT NULL,
    EndTime Time NOT NULL
)
```

You would use it like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.StartTime as RoundedDown
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN TimeMap b 
    ON b.StartTime <= CAST(a.SomeDateTime AS time) AND CAST(a.SomeDateTime AS time) < b.EndTime)


SELECT a.*, b.EndTime as RoundedUp
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN TimeMap b 
    ON b.StartTime < CAST(a.SomeDateTime AS time) AND CAST(a.SomeDateTime AS time) <= b.EndTime)
```

Note that I've never done this with time tables, but I've done the same thing with date tables.

Comment: do i need to create temporary table ? given by your sample?

Comment: It would be a real table. That way it's always available for future queries.